# Mashup Qlik Sense - MIME invalido

Tags: angular, mime-types, mime, qliksense

I am using Mashup with Angular 1.0.0 in Qlik Sense, when I import the application in the browser I have the following error:

```
"The {my script path} script was loaded even though its MIME type ("text / html") is not a valid Javascript MIME type"
```

All scripts inside html are being specified with type = "text / javascript", I found nothing related to this documentation flaw.

Comment: Are you running it on the qlik sense server or localhost:4848 (node instance of Qlik Sense Desktop)?

Comment: qlik sense server

Comment: Can you show the code of your JS file?